# what would a .htaccess look like for Elm-Land?

Tags: .htaccess

The [deployment documentation](https://elm.land/guide/deploying.html) for https://elm.land states:

> All Elm Land apps are compiled as "single-page applications" in the
> dist folder. This means no matter what page is requested, that request
> will need to be directed to a single file: dist/index.html.
>
> Depending on your hosting provider, you may need to add some
> configuration to tell it to redirect all URL requests to the
> dist/index.html file.

What would a modified .htaccess look like?

These settings aren't working for me and no Elm Land content is being returned.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^ /dist/index.html [L]
```

Comment: Where are your files located (in relation to the document root)? What URL are you requesting?

Comment: they are: dist/index.html, dist/main.css, dist/ol.css, assets/*.js

Comment: It said all requests should be directed to the `dist/index.html` file, whereas you are rewriting to just `/index.html`. (Assuming your `.htaccess` is in the same folder that `dist` is in, and that that folder is your document root.)

Comment: thanks. I've update the question to a broader rule I tried. I've also put the app on netlify which doesn't use .htaccess and the app ran. So, I think the issue is in my setup on the apache server.